# How to reshard the indices to overcome latency during high traffic in elasticsearch cluster

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

During high traffic times, our Elasticsearch cluster is experiencing latency, and we are considering a resharding strategy to optimize performance. Below is our current index setup and the proposed resharding plan:

```
Current Indices:

billing-index-v0.0: 45 GB, 20 shards (over-sharded)
billing-index-v1.0: 197 GB, 20 shards (over-sharded)
billing-index-v2.0: 1.4 GB, 20 shards (over-sharded)
billing-index-v4.0: 947 GB, 20 shards (over-populated)

Proposed Resharding: (25 GB Aimed per shard)

billing-index-v0.1: 45 GB, 2 shards
billing-index-v1.1: 197 GB, 8 shards
billing-index-v2.1: 1.4 GB, 2 shards
billing-index-v4.1: 947 GB, 40 shards
```

Questions:

1. Will the proposed resharding strategy help alleviate latency during
   high traffic times?
2. Are there any potential drawbacks or considerations we should be aware of?
3. Should we consider a different resharding approach based on our current setup?

Query patterns:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "accountId": "9812374287423"
              }
            },
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "linkedAccount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isDeleted": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Kelly",
            "fields": [
              "firstName.autocomplete",
              "lastName.autocomplete",
              "fullName.autocomplete",
              "emailId.autocomplete",
              "phone.autocomplete",
              "companyName.autocomplete",
              "country.autocomplete",
              "state.autocomplete",
              "city.autocomplete",
              "address.autocomplete"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "modifiedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hardware specifications: 4 Nodes, 16 Core CPUs, 32 GB Memory.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

20 Primary shards each with 1 replica = 40 shards in total, per index

Elasticsearch version 7.9

Application server request for
High traffic - Search (/search route) 350/min , 5/s
Low traffic - Search (/search route) 160/min , 2.5/s

We are using alias name for reading from the indices billing-alias
billing-index-v0.0, Search, Update only,
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 0.18/S, Primary Shards - 0.09/s
Search Rate - 155/s (high traffic) 33/s low traffic (number of search requests being executed across primary and replica shards)

billing-index-v1.0, Search, Update Only
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 1.78/S, Primary Shards - 0.88/s
Search Rate - 152/s (high traffic) 33/s low traffic

billing-index-v2.0, Search, Update Only
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 0.04/S, Primary Shards - 0.02/s
Search Rate - 157/s (high traffic) 34/s low traffic

billing-index-v3.0, Search, Update Only
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 4.65/S, Primary Shards - 2.28/s
Search Rate - 157/s (high traffic) 40/s low traffic

billing-index-v4.0, Search, Update Only
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 19.6/s, Primary Shards - 9.58/s
Search Rate - 158/s (high traffic) 33/s low traffic

billing-index-v5.0, Write, Search, Update (Current write index where new docs getting created)
Indexing Rate - Total Shards 16.64/S, Primary Shards - 8.05/s
Search Rate - 155/s (high traffic) 33/s low traffic

Average size of the document is 900 bytes.

Storage type SSD Persistant Disk

Disk IOPS

**Write:**
Max: 0.08k/s
Mean: 0.07/s
Min: 0.06/s

**Read**
Max: 1.99k/s
Mean: 1.19/s
Min: 0.8k/s

CPU is well within 20 percent even during high traffic time and as far heap usage is concerned no memory pressure observed. No frequent GCs and always stays within 70 and cycles

Comment: It is impossible to tell. You need to understand why you have latency. First of all, where do you experience latency ? Ingest ? search ? When you have high traffic, does your search threadpool is queueing ? If so, what are the search queries done ? and then you dig :D

Comment: What are the mappings for fields ˋaccountId` and ˋisDeleted` ? And did you try to add replicas because it helps for search performance.

Comment: Hi @Paulo . The latency is observed in search. The search queue is not getting overflowed during high traffic. No rejections

Comment: Hi @Jean-PierreMatsumoto. accountId is keyword field and isDeleted is boolean. Yes 20 Primary with 1 replica for each. 40 shards per index. Have updated more information about the cluster